# Can not get access to private property defined in component inside call back function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For demonstrating purpose, I have declared the following inside my app.component.ts just before my constructor

```
private testObjArray = []
```

Inside my ngOnInit, I have the following

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log('test 1', this.testObjArray);

    this.testObjArray = [1];

    console.log('test 2', this.testObjArray);

    this.databaseService.getNotification()
    .on('child_added', function (obj) {
        console.log('test 3', this.testObjArray); // <--- this is where the problem is
    })
}
```

where inside my database.service.ts

```
getNotificationsForCurrentUser() {
    let currentUser = this.userService.getCurrentUser()
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('notifications/')
    return ref;
}
```

In this case, I am sure that .on is triggered as I have data inside my database. 
What I am finding is that INSIDE call back from getNotifications() from firebase, I could not seem to get any of my properties declared at the top of my app 
For example, the console output for the above code is

```
test 1 []
test 2 [1]
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'testObjArray' of null
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'testObjArray' of null
```

I need to get a reference to this.testObjArray inside my .getNotification().on function such that I can update my template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `this` inside your callback function is not your class context; it is bound to the object that the event was triggered on.

To solve this you can use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will capture the correct `this`:

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log('test 1', this.testObjArray);

    this.testObjArray = [1];

    console.log('test 2', this.testObjArray);

    this.databaseService.getNotification()
    .on('child_added', (obj) => { // Notice arrow function here
        console.log('test 3', this.testObjArray); //
    })
}
```

---

Another option would be to capture the `this` variable before your callback:

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log('test 1', this.testObjArray);

    this.testObjArray = [1];

    console.log('test 2', this.testObjArray);
    let that = this; // Capture `this` here
    this.databaseService.getNotification()
    .on('child_added', function (obj) {
        console.log('test 3', that.testObjArray); // ... and use it here
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` you're using inside your function is actually the function object, so you can set it to a variable outside the function to gain access to the `this` that you wanted. You're creating a closure, so it's a matter of the context of `this` where you're accessing it.

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log('test 1', this.testObjArray);

    this.testObjArray = [1];

    console.log('test 2', this.testObjArray);

    var that = this;

    this.databaseService.getNotification()
    .on('child_added', function (obj) {
        console.log('test 3', that.testObjArray); 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this`:

```
function (obj) {
    console.log('test 3', this.testObjArray); // <--- this is where the problem is
}.bind(this)
```

Or, you could always use a lambda expression (arrow function) which is an es6 construct.

```
(obj) => console.log('test 3', this.testObjArray)
```